# How many times a file was requested from a server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp

Is it somehow possible to see how many times a specific file was requested from the server, or set up a system to see it in the future?

In my case, it is a Javascript file on my server that is included on many different websites.

My setup is using LAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that JSON file is requested by HTTP requests going to your Apache server.

That server probably manages log files. (the location of that log file is configurable).

You then need to scan the [access log file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) to find every access. You can use something like

```
grep yourfile.json /var/log/www/access.log | wc
```

(to count occurrences)
where `/var/log/www/access.log` is your access log file.

BTW, many log files are managed by [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). Details are system specific. Take than into account too.

Answer (score 2):

You can see requests in an [access log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) of Apache server.

Simply scan for occurrences of requests to that file by hands or write some script.